# "Discover" vs "discovered that."

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language

I thought that "that" was unnecessary in sentences like:

> I discovered (that) you can't fake sadness.

Google books surprised me though:

[I discovered you](https://www.google.com.tw/search?client=ubuntu&hs=kMY&biw=1855&bih=984&tbm=bks&ei=igYWXdapNOWPr7wP3vqVqAc&q=%22I%20discovered%20you%20%22&oq=%22I%20discovered%20you%20%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...25195.25332.0.25401.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.2t0ZriFsU2c) (12,300 hits)

[I discovered that you](http://I%20d%20iscovered%20you) (137,000 hits)

Why is this?

Comment: I think that in every example I can think of "that" isn't necessary and can be left out and in some cases is actually wrong unless the sentence is changed. "_I discovered you in the room_" but "_I discovered that you **were in** the room_". Also the meaning can be subtly different.  "_I discovered you in the room_" means that I went into the room and found you whilst "_I discovered that you were in the room_" ***could*** mean that somebody told me you were there although the first meaning is also possible.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's exactly a "reason", but following the principle that "less is more" (shorter is better), many people would probably go for ***I found you can't fake sadness***. But did you really "research" this issue in order to make this "finding, discovery"? Probably not, so you may as well say ***I think you can't fake sadness***, where those first two words are contextually completely superfluous anyway, so there's not much point in including them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"That" is used to introduce a clause, which is a sequence of words that function as a single grammatical element in a larger sentence. When we write:

> I discovered that you can't fake sadness.

"To discover" takes an object: the thing being discovered. The object here is the clause "you can't fake sadness," and "that" introduces it. It serves as a marker for the reader's brain, signaling that there are going to be several words coming up which have to be taken together to tell us what was discovered.

In common speech and writing, it is reasonably common to leave out "that," as you found. But it *should* be present when a clause takes the place of a grammatical element, such as the object of a verb. If you leave it out, it may make the sentence harder to understand, especially if the clause is long and complex. The reader may have to backtrack in order to parse the sentence when they don't have the appropriate or expected cues.

Comment: I agree that omitting the "that" sometimes makes the sentence ambiguous, particularly in writing, and that may well be why the OP found more instances with "that" than without. But I don't agree that there is any "should" about it.

Comment: Even in writing, it's often better to drop *that* IMO. I think a lot of things feed into the judgment about whether to drop it or not - formality is one of them, but  there's more to that than written vs spoken. Potential ambiguity is another, and beyond that there are considerations of prosody and balance between different elements of the sentence, paragraph etc.